# Swift - specialized _VariantDictionaryBuffer.ensureUniqueNativeBuffer(Int)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, fabric.io

I'm a bit new here with swift error.
My app experiencing specialied error, that i can't figure it out for quite sometimes.

Can anyone suggest on how to tackle this problem and what usually causes Specialized error ?

Here is there error report that i got.

```
 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183cf12ec __pthread_kill + 8
 1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183e966a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360
 2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x183c5fd0c abort + 140
 3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x183d29838 szone_size + 634
 4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x104078f10 _swift_release_dealloc + 28
 5  AppMy                             0x1021b45b8 specialized _VariantDictionaryBuffer.ensureUniqueNativeBuffer(Int) -> (reallocated : Bool, capacityChanged : Bool) (WatchListStockViewController.swift)
 6  AppMy                             0x1021b5a14 specialized specialized _VariantDictionaryBuffer.nativeUpdateValue(B, forKey : A) -> B? (WatchListStockViewController.swift)
 7  AppMy                          0x1021b612c specialized WatchListStockViewController.updateCompanies(String, widget : JSON) -> () (WatchListStockViewController.swift:1065)
 8  AppMy                          0x1021b67dc specialized WatchListStockViewController.fireSocketMessage(JSON) -> () (WatchListStockViewController.swift:1039)
 9  AppMy                          0x1021b96d8 partial apply for WatchListStockViewController.(subscribeWebSocket() -> ()).(closure #1) (WatchListStockViewController.swift:200)
 10 AppMy                          0x102538318 JSON (StreamHomeViewController.swift)
 11 AppMy                          0x1022abb70 specialized SockJSManager.handleChannel(JSON) -> () + 4369972080
 12 AppMy                          0x1022a8514 SockJSManager.(handleMessage(response : String) -> ()).(closure #1) (SockJSManager.swift:399)
 13 AppMy                          0x10250c28c _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR (BaseViewController.swift)
 14 libdispatch.dylib              0x183b5cb24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
 15 libdispatch.dylib              0x183b5cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
 16 libdispatch.dylib              0x183b98528 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 700
 17 libdispatch.dylib              0x183b9e3a4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 592
 18 libdispatch.dylib              0x183b9e0f0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
 19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183e8ffac _pthread_wqthread + 1176
 20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183e8fb08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to help debugging exceptions in general, this [Xcode Help page](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devfeaa874d0) describes how to create exception breakpoints. It would be helpful to know what kind of exception was actually thrown here - maybe an `EXP_BAD_ACCESS`?

---

Now to your specific crash.

The word "specialized" doesn't really characterize the problem here, it only indicates that the called method signatures were derived from [generic ones](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html).

Further, to really know what's going on, one would need to see the source code of `WatchListStockViewController.updateCompanies(String, widget : JSON)`.

What I can tell from your stack trace is that your app crashes when trying to update a value in a `_VariantDictionaryBuffer`, which is used as the underlying data structure for `Dictionary`. Given that dictionaries in Swift aren't thread safe, and your code is running in a dispatch queue, seemingly handling (parallel?) WebSockets, the error might be caused by **concurrent read/write access** to some dictionary that contains "company" information. Could `WatchListStockViewController.updateCompanies` be called from different threads at the same time?

Again, without knowing the code it is really hard to tell what exactly is going wrong, maybe you can attach a snippet to your question ...